# Is there a way to get data out of a 303 redirect or cancel it?

Tags: javascript, http, axios

I have a Nuxt.js app using Typescript and Axios and I'm working with an API that interacts the following way for a POST request:

- If the resource doesn't exist, it will be created, back-end returns a 201 and the `Location` header points to the created resource.
- If it already exists, back-end returns a 303 and the `Location` header points to the existing resource.

In case of a 303 redirect, the browser is always making an extra GET request on that `Location` header value that points to the resource.

In the front-end, I would like to get the response of this call, or prevent default behaviour and call the back-end myself, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the github issue and axios docs: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/674 you can see that you have a `maxRedirect` option to not automatically follow redirects. This is only working on Node environments.

The issue was closed with guidance to take a look at fetch which is able to support this use case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options.

Axios also has a `beforeRedirect()` configuration, but from the documentation it is not clear if this would be called from browsers. So most likely the answer is no. With axios and browsers you are not able to intercept these requests.

A work around is either using fetch or proxy your request via the backend where you pipe the request with `maxRedirect:0`.

Comment: Just curious to know why axios cannot do it in a browser environment if fetch can

Comment: fetch is natively implemented in the browser nowadays with new capabilities. Axios is using XHR under the hood: https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/v1.x/lib/adapters

Comment: Mhmmm, yes you're right, I remember reading that